# Java, Hibernate,JPA, ORM @GeneratedValue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Buenos dias quisiera porfavor saber para que sirven estas dos anotaciones en programacion. ?

Es mejor que un Id autonumerico de tipo int ?

```
@GeneratedValue(generator ="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid",strategy="uuid")
```

Answer (score 0):

`@GeneratedValue(generator ="system-uuid")` Es una anotación de Hibernate para indicar la estrategia de generacion de los valores ID de la tabla. Por lo tanto se usa sobre la propiedad de la clase que se corresponde con el campo llave de la tabla. Tu estas usando el generador `system-uuid`

`@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid",strategy="uuid")` Indica que estas usando generador de IDs predefinido en el sistema o por el usuario: en este caso la estrategia uuid es definida por el sistema. Se le debe poner un nombre para que la puedas usar. En este caso la usas con la anotación `GeneratedValue`.

Entonces en resumen con esas dos anotaciones generas IDs tipo [UUID](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_%C3%BAnico_universal)